# Найти строки, в которых последние две или три цифры отличны от заданных

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Не могу подобрать выражение, чтобы получить строки, в конце которых нет заданных цифр, например:
985тест193
859тесттест93
758тесттттт23
888тееест696

и вот мне нужно получить строки, в которых в конце нет цифры "193", или "23"..
при этом количество цифр после текста может быть разным, собственно, как и количество цифр в запросе.

Comment: (?<!\d)193(?!\d), но  не могу тут указать отрицание...

Comment: Уточните: 1. Какие символы могут входить в нужные подстроки. 2 Какой диалект регулярных выражений (или в каком языке программирования будут использоваться).

Comment: Выражение будет использоваться в запросе к БД PostgreSQL. Искомые символы - только цифры. Ищем в строках, где есть и буквы и цифры.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Такое подойдёт?

```
/(?<!\S)\S+(?<!\D93)(?!\S)/
```

Comment: Ай спасибо!!!!
Можно еще вопрос, как теперь сделать, чтобы когда я указывал (?<!\S)\S+(?<!93)(?!\S), то строка, в которой последняя цифра "193" не попадала под это правило? То есть учитывалась длина строки в запросе..

Comment: Не понимаю) Ведь для `/(?<!\S)\S+(?<!193)(?!\S)/` строка, в которой последняя цифра "193", уже не подпадает под регулярку, в этом же её смысл?

Comment: 93 и 193 - в моем случае разные задачи..Если в запросе указано  НЕ выбирать строки с последней цифрой 93, то строки, в которых последняя цифра 193 - не должны попадать в это правило. Другими словами, строка "тестест193"  и строка "тесттестеее93" - в моем случае имеют разную последнюю цифру (не одну цифру, и всю цифру в конце).

Comment: В вашем варианте, если я в запросе укажу !93, то строка с цифрой на конце "193", или "493" так же окажется в числе отсеяных.

Comment: То есть в исключениях указывается не часть числа, а всё число после букв?

Comment: Если да, попробуйте новый вариант в ответе.

Comment: Верно!!! Именно все число нужно "ловить", оно может состоять из двух цифр, может из трех..
Другими словами - если в запросе пришло трехзначное число - сравниваем с последними тремя цифрами в конце строк (даже если в искомой строке в конце всего две цифры, эти строки уже отсеиваем), если пришло двухзначное число - сравниваем с двумя цифрами в конце строк (а если в искомых строках, в конце три цифры, а не две - то эти строки так же отсеиваем как изначально не устраивающие условиям). Все последние числа строго после букв.

Comment: Работает ли новый вариант?

Comment: Спасибо!!!!! заработало....